# MariaDB changing column type locks the table?

Tags: mariadb, innodb, alter-table

I was looking for better documentation, of what happens behind the scene when you change column definition.

i.e. I want to change a column type from tinyint to int, and my table has 4+ million records.

So, running alter table change query will lock the table? If yes what kind of that lock will be?

Any resources are appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: partial - [InnoDB DDL lock](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-online-ddl-overview/#lock). Your operation I believe requires a COPY, which is exclusive table lock, queries on that table will lock wait until the change is complete.

Answer (score 0):

An `ALTER TABLE` that needs to change how the data is stored will lock the table, copy the data over, rebuild indexes, and swap the new table into place.

In your one example, `TINYINT` occupies 1 byte in storage; `INT` occupies 4 bytes.  So the "copy" is needed.

Increasing the max on `VARCHAR`, at least while staying below 255, does not really need to change the storage, so it probably simply (and very quickly) changes the table definition without copying data over.  If you shrank the max, there is the issue of truncating strings that are too long.

If a column is indexed, then the index would need, or not need, rebuilding based on similar considerations.

See `pt-online-schema-change` for a way to `ALTER` a large table with virtually no downtime.